# How can i do titles for every 7 columns (besides first 3)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have

```
 df
Out[92]: 
               MAIN TITLE 
   S  K  L  Z  X  C  V  Z  X  C  V  Z  X  C  V  
a  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
b  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I want

```
 df
Out[92]: 
               MAIN TITLE
                B           C           D     
   S  K  L  Z  X  C  V  Z  X  C  V  Z  X  C  V  
a  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
b  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

I saw smth like https://question-it.com/questions/1200269/kak-ja-mogu-sozdat-mnogourovnevyj-zagolovok-v-pandas-dataframe, but...

Comment: What is `print (df.columns)` ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: я только учусь писать вопросы сюда, а у меня там много строчек, поэтому я не знаю насколько это будет вообще удобный вопрос по итогу и какие именно строки добавлять в вопрос...

Answer (score 0):

If `MultiIndex` in original DataFrame extract first nd second level by [`Index.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) and recreate 3 levels MultiIndex by mapping `arange` with integer division by list `vals`:

```
vals = ['B','C','D']

N = 7
a = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
b = df.columns.get_level_values(1)

di = dict(enumerate(vals))
c = [di.get(x,x) for x in np.arange(len(df.columns)) // N]

df.columns = [a,c,b]
print (df)
  MAIN TITLE                                          
           B                    C                    D
           S  K  L  Z  X  C  V  Z  X  C  V  Z  X  C  V
a          0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
b          1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```